# how to use jmeter functions in loop controller

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

My test plan is below
![TestPlan
     ThreadGroup
        LoopController1
             Sampler1
               BeanShellPostProcessor
               Listener
        LoopController2
             Sampler2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL1Gt.jpg)

As part of Beanshellpostprocessor, i am putting count value to a variable
props.put("noOfRecords",vars.get("msg_#"));

Now this value i am placing on 2nd loopcontroller as ${__P(noOfRecords,0)}

This setup is failing for iterations where we don't have any records. So the previous "${__P(noOfRecords,0)}" value is considered while running the Loop2.

Is there any other way we can achieve the dynamic loop counter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables or properties in the Loop Controller to change the loop count at run time.

If the Property/Variable is set correctly by the Beanshell postprocessor in your test, It should work. That is, you need to set the value to 0 explicitly when there is no record. Otherwise Properties (which are not destroyed until you close JMeter) might use the previous value.

Comment: Yes thats correct, i am setting the default value as 0 by ${__P(noOfRecords,0)} but still the previous value is considered. Is there any way that i can reset the value for every iteration. i.e setting 0 for props variable at the start of beanshell postprocessor and update the value at the end of it. Tried this approach but when i print the value, its the old one.

Comment: Can you upload your .jmx file?

Comment: it got resolved . The catch was the props values were getting updated once the postprocessor is done executing. So for the next iteration, the value would be the old one till we set it as part of postprocessor again. Thanks for the help